# What is the name of this anime with a green-haired henchman being tickled?

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

This is the video in question. A young boy tickles a green-haired goon with a mohawk.

Comment: Looks more like an American cartoon than anime, although he could be speaking Japanese.

Comment: Wow, that henchman looks a lot like Megumu Koyama from Mob Psycho 100.

Comment: Just a pro tip for anyone trying to solve this one: Google "anime tickling scene" and related terms at your own risk. Here's just one example of what I found: http://animefeet.wikia.com/wiki/Tickling (yes, that wikia has almost 9000 articles)

Comment: @Alan According to a friend who knows Japanese, it's Chinese

Answer (score 3):

This is a Chinese show called 奇幻龙宝第 ("Fantasy Dragon Treasure"). Its English name is [Jackie Chan's Fantasia](https://www.lostmediawiki.com/Jackie_Chan%27s_Fantasia_(partially_found_English_dub_of_Chinese_animated_series;_2011)). There were 52 episodes made in Chinese, but only the first 13 are available in English. A summary of the show can be found [here](https://www.allrightsentertainment.com/product-page/jackie-chan-s-fantasia) in English and [here](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%A5%87%E5%B9%BB%E9%BE%99%E5%AE%9D) in Chinese (the Chinese page is better).

Does nobody recognize Jackie Chan?

The clip is from episode 7: 穿越时空 ("Crossing Time and Space"):

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoUJXkhrFIkdJHBYtfnHDU81N2_yE8J4P) is a playlist of some full episodes in Chinese.

---

I found this with a search for 幻光鞋 ("magic shoes").