# Jackie Chan anime (not "Jackie Chan Adventures")

Tags: story-identification, anime

There was an anime I used to see; it aired on either old Disney XD or Animax. It aired around 2012 or 2014 I guess, but it didn't air for so long. It had a story very much related to the anime "Jackie Chan Adventures". The MC had to travel to receive magical things. There were even some desert and train scenes, if it helps.

Answer (score 5):

This might be *[Jackie Chan's Fantasia](https://www.tvtime.com/en/show/363674)*.

[image]

From the [Jackie Chan Adventures Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackie_Chan_Adventures):

> Following Jackie Chan Adventures, Chan set off to create local productions in Asia. The first, Jackie Chan's Fantasia, is a 52-episode Chinese animated series produced by Nanjing Hongying Animation Entertainment. It aired in 2009 on CCTV and in English on Sonic-Nickelodeon.

Comment: This is also the answer to [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167429/82909). In that answer I have a link to all the episodes in Chinese. Only 13 of the episodes were ever translated to English.

Comment: @Gaurav Mishra - If this answer is correct, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark just beneath the voting arrows.